# Can a Windows service install another Windows service?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, service, permissions, teamcity

I am having trouble when I have one Windows service try to install another Windows service.

Specifically, I have a TeamCity agent running tests for me on a Windows 2008 AWS instance. The tests are written in Java, which shell out to a .bat script to install a service (let's call it Service A), giving it a unique name each time.

The offending line is in the .bat script: `sc create "%serviceName%" binPath= %binPath% DisplayName= "%serviceDisplayName:"=%" start= %serviceStartType%`. I believe as long as the service name is unique that should work.

And indeed it does work if I run the tests manually on the command line, using an administrator account. Service A is installed, the test completes and Service A is uninstalled at the end.

I have tried running the TeamCity agent as LocalSystem, as Administrator, and as another user that is member of the administrators group. I have also tried disabling UAC completely.

Presumably the problem is access denied type errors, although that is not clear at this point. There are a few avenues to explore still, but it is a simple question really: are processes running as services forbidden from installing other services? Are there special things I have to do to configure the machine/ account to allow it to do this?

The point of the test it to install and use Service A, so workarounds are not relevant - Service A must be operated as a black box.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please try making a test .bat file where you use the literal values of the service name you want to get created instead of using the env vars of %serviceName%, etc. I suspect your Java process may not have the same environment as your cmd shell, and so what is actually getting executed there is different. Otherwise, please put a pause at the end of your .bat script so that you can actually see the error being printed out so that we can evaluate what the real problem is.

Comment: It is possible, so you need more logging to find to culprit.
Try echo followed by a copy of the command, just before. You can redirect to a file if TC does not capture it.

Comment: If %binPath% has spaces in it I believe you'll need to put double-quotes around it.

Comment: Thanks @jon, giulio-vian, harry-johnston, you were right: LocalSystem _can_ install services, even without tweaking UAC; it was my environment that was misconfigured. I guess I was fixated and despairing, sorry!

Answer (score 2):

There are no restrictions on creating services with regards to *how* the creating process can execute, as long as the process has the appropriate permissions. That is to say, a process could be running as a service and create another service -- the only consideration here is the appropriate permission level.

The problem that often occurs with running batch scripts from within processes (as opposed to directly through user input on the command line) is that the environment expected isn't always the environment that is loaded. In this case, it appears that the env variables referred to in the batch script weren't properly set when running as a service, which of course then caused the service install failure. Correcting the environment loaded when the batch script is shelled out is the correct solution here.